# Cancancan ActiveAdmin: skip authorization for :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, cancancan

I'm using Cancancan for authorization in ActiveAdmin.
Everything work fine except the :create. When create a new admin, cancancan will check is admin_user.id = id. However, ActiveAdmin make id = nil, so I can't create a new admin.

```
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(admin_user)
    can :manage, AdminUser, id: admin_user.id
    ....

  end
end
```

My solution is everyone can skip authorization for create.
My application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource 
  skip_authorize_resource :only => :new  
end
```

but it does nothing. Please help!

Comment: _everyone can skip authorization for create_ so everyone can create admin? What the purpose of admin if everyone can create them?

Comment: also `new` isn't `create` it's two different actions.

Comment: In my project, admin is considered as a normal user. Sorry for the confusion. I tried both 'new' and 'create' but nothing work.

Comment: So who do you want to be able to create admin users?

Comment: Yeah, in my project right now there is only one type of user (admin) and I want everyone can create anything they want. (create new admin, create new post,..)

Comment: @matthewng its unclear what the problem you have, could you show all related errors, logs and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify what actions need authorization like this...

```
def initialize(admin_user)
  can [:edit, :destroy], AdminUser, id: admin_user.id
end
```

Just replace/add to `[:edit, :destroy]` with whatever actions you need that authorization for.

If you want all admin users to be able to perform an action on AdminUser...

```
can :some_action, AdminUser
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day! I never though about combine those two abilities. Have a good day/night man!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!